# Substring Search with Syscall

Tags: c, search, substring

I'm trying to do a substring search using sys call where I open a file from the command line, and compare the following command line arguments to the file. I want to output the number of occurrences of each substring. For example, if I wrote ./a.out filename aa b I am looking for the number of times aa and b occurs in filename.

My code so far

```
for(int num = 4; num < argc; num++)
    {
      int fp = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY);
      int sizeofbar = strlen(argv[1]);
      char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeofbar+1);
      int count = 0;  //counter for output                                  
      char* string2 = argv[num];
      int sizeofcompare = strlen(string2);

      read(fp, buf, sizeofcompare);
      while (strstr(buf, string2) != NULL)
        {

          count++;
          buf++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some initialization before entering your loop. Perhaps you want to take the first argument off first:

```
filename = argv[0];    
argv++;
argc--;
int fp = open(...
```

Next, I'd pre-process the rest of the arguments to build a data structure to store it. You can use the argc value to determine how many words you'll need to track.

```
counts = (int *)calloc(argc, sizeof(int));
```

Note that this will initialize the values to zero for you too.

With everything setup, then I'd read through the entire file contents and compare to the strings. The trick is in comparing multiple different length strings at once. A simple yet inefficient method is to read the entire file contents in and then loop using strstr for each word that follows the filename. Another method would be mapping the file's contents into memory and scanning it directly (letting the operating system do the heavy lifting).